# $a^2+b^2<1+a^2b^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If $a<1$ and $b<1$ then how do I prove that
     $a^2+b^2<1+a^2b^2$

I stumble across this equation while solving a problem from complex analysis i.e.
         $$|a-b|/|1-(\bar{a})b|<1 \ \mbox{if } |a|<1 \mbox{ and } |b|<1$$
where $\bar{a}$ = conjugate of a.
can we prove second without proving first?

Comment: Hint: compute $(1-a^2)(1-b^2)$.

Comment: The inequality can be easily solved by subtracting $1$ and $b^2$ followed by factoring out $a^2-1$ on the right side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $0< x< 1$ and $0<y<1$ then prove $x+y<1+xy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103750/if-0x1-and-0y1-then-prove-xy1xy)

Comment: And your second  question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1630930/42969.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$(1-a^2)(1-b^2)>0$$

if $1-a^2,1-b^2>0\iff a^2,b^2<1\iff-1<a,b<1$

or if both $<0$